# Aggregating Using Proc SQL

Tags: sas

Suppose I've a dataset in the form:

```
A B C
1 3 5
1 4 8
1 3 3
2 2 2
2 7 6
2 3 3
3 4 4 
3 4 7
3 2 8
```

Now, I want to take weighted average of each segment of A and then add them up over A. For example in A var for 1, I want to take the weighted avg as (3*5+4*8+3*3)/(3+4+3). And then add up to get 5.6. Same with other 2 segments of A. So, finally the table looks like the following:

```
A B C   D
1 3 7 5.6
2 6 6 7
3 5 9 8.2
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the solution below. I am curious about your result. For A=2, the weighted average should be (2*2+7*6+3*3)/(2+7+3), about 4.5. Why here you have 7?

```
data test;
input a  b  c ;
datalines;
1 3 5
1 4 8
1 3 3
2 2 2
2 7 6
2 3 3
3 4 4 
3 4 7
3 2 8
;
run;

proc sql;
create table agg as 
select a, b, c, sum(b*c)/sum(b) as d from test
group by a;
quit;

proc sort data=agg nodupkey;
by a d;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Robbie! Strangely I was using the same statement (without proc sort) but it was not giving me the result. But thanks again. As for avg, I just randomly put it. Not a calculated value.

Answer (score 7):

Just to provide an alternative approach, you can use the WEIGHT statement in PROC SUMMARY to achieve the same result.  The only thing I'm not clear on from your example final table table is where the values of columns B & C come from (I've left these out of my solution below).

```
    proc summary data=test nway;
    class a;
    var c / weight=b;
    output out=agg2 (drop=_:) mean=d;
    run;
```

Comment: Thanks Keith for your answer. The values of B & C are given in raw data. We want to create a new var using B & C, conditional on A.

Comment: +1 for the /weight= syntax - I didn't know you could set different weights for different variables in the same summary. Thanks!